Trino - How do I filter on dates
Just started to use Salesforce and I'm using DBeaver to query the data.
I've been using MSSQL for 15 years but this is my first time using Trino SQL and running into issues when doing the most basic things like filtering on dates.
All I want to do is a simple SELECT between a date range.
I've tried all sorts of different things and documentation I've found doesn't answer this basic question.


Can you not add a WHERE CreatedDate_C > MYSQLDATEFORMAT < CreatedDate_C?  Filter your range like that?

@easleyfixed Tried that but I get an error CreatedDate__c >= '2024-04-25 21:27:20.547 UTC'

@easleyfixed I've tried  CAST(CreatedDate as DATE) >= ............... but same issue.

As in :  CAST(CreatedDate as DATE) >= '2024-04-25'

@easleyfixed Yeah thought that would be the best way of doing it, but same error.
I'm thinking its not me but something with how things are set up.

@easleyfixed I found this to work WHERE CreatedDate__c >= DATE'2024-06-06'
AND CreatedDate__c <= DATE'2024-06-12'

There we go, yeah have to cast as date and must be in mysql date format, but you got it, good job.

To filter on dates you need dates on both sides of the comparison.  '2024-04-25 21:27:20.547 UTC' is not a date literal and would not be converted to one in Trino. If the CreatedDate_C column is of date/timestamp type (can be checked with select typeof(CreatedDate_C)) then the following should work:
WHERE CreatedDate_C > timestamp '2024-04-25 21:27:20.547 UTC'; -- or date '2024-04-25' 

or
WHERE CreatedDate_C BETWEEN timestamp '2024-04-25 21:27:20.547 UTC' 
   AND timestamp '2025-04-25 21:27:20.547 UTC';

If CreatedDate_C is not date/timestamp then you will need to cast it or parse it to one.

I found this to work
WHERE CreatedDate__c >= DATE'2024-06-06'
AND CreatedDate__c <= DATE'2024-06-12'

@lezs76 yes, as the answer suggests (see the comment in the first snippet).
